# Keras: Lambda layer function with multiple parameters

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to write a `Lambda` layer in Keras which calls a function `connection`, that runs a loop `for i in range(0,k)` where `k` is fed in as an input to the function, `connection(x,k)`. Now, when I try to call the function in the Functional API, I tried using:

```
k = 5
y = Lambda(connection)(x)
```

Also,

```
y = Lambda(connection)(x,k)
```

But neither of those approaches worked. How can I feed in the value of `k` without assigning it as a global parameter?

Comment: Is "k" a constant? Or is it calculated somewhere in the model? Is it an input to the model, as part of the input data?

Comment: `k` updates through the model. The value of `k` changes for different times I call the `Lambda` layer. But I found the solution [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/1911), in a Keras GitHub Issue. Using `y = Lambda(connection, arguments={'k':k})(x)` worked!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use

```
y = Lambda(connection)((x,k))
```

and then var[0], var[1] in connection method

Comment: This is the correct solution which should have been accepted.

Comment: This will not work unless both `x` and `k` are Tensor objects (cf : `Layer lambda_4 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'int'>. Full input: [8]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.`)

Comment: @ArthurAttout python variables can be passed to Lambda using local context

Comment: I throws error "connection missing 1 required positional argument k" in the newest tensorflow

Answer (score 15):

Found the solution to the problem in [this GitHub Pull Request](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/1911). Using

```
y = Lambda(connection, arguments={'k':k})(x)
```

worked!

Comment: Note: by default `model.save_weights()` will not recognize `k` as part of the model.

Comment: Yes, this worked indeed. But for the other readers.. please know that the variable k here is already defined as some constant

Answer (score 4):

```
Tmodel = Sequential()
x = layers.Input(shape=[1,])   # Lambda on single input
out1 = layers.Lambda(lambda x: x ** 2)(x)

y = layers.Input(shape=[1,])   # Lambda on multiple inputs
z = layers.Input(shape=[1,])
def conn(IP):
    return IP[0]+IP[1]
out2 = layers.Lambda(conn)([y,z])

Tmodel = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x,y,z], outputs=[out1,out2],name='Tmodel')  # Define Model
Tmodel.summary()

# output
O1,O2 = Tmodel([2,15,10])
print(O1)   # tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int32)
print(O2)   # tf.Tensor(25, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for better clarity or reference documentation.